# Adding one extra row to the result of MySQL select query

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table like this

```
id   Name   count
1    ABC    1
2    CDF    3
3    FGH    4
```

using simply select query I get the values as

```
1    ABC    1
2    CDF    3
3    FGH    4
```

How I can get the result like this

```
1    ABC    1
2    CDF    3
3    FGH    4
4    NULL   0
```

You can see Last row. When Records are finished an extra row in this format 
`last_id+1, Null ,0` should be added. You can see above. Even I have no such row in my original table. There may be N rows not fixed 3,4

Comment: you can't. Until it actually exists in the table.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd I'm not sure that's true.

Comment: @Nerd-Herd I'm sure that is not true.

Comment: @Warrior have a look at simplest way. 1 line query. gives you what you need

Comment: @Warrior - is it always just one row, with an ID 1 higher than the highest one in the table? Then Sami Akram's answer is correct, and I'll take back my downvote.

Comment: as you want to add one row so you can try
select * from 'urtable' union select (select max(id)+1),'NULL','0'; hopefully you will get desired result. No matter how much rows you have

Comment: @Warrior did you get the answer? Have you tried the query in my above comment?

Comment: You can using a union if you are not sure don't say you can't.

Answer (score 11):

The answer is very simple

```
select (select max(id) from mytable)+1 as id, NULL as Name, 0 as count union all select id,Name,count from mytable;
```

Comment: This is the most accurate answer I have come accross.

Answer (score 3):

This looks a little messy but it should work.

```
SELECT a.id, b.name, coalesce(b.`count`) as `count`
FROM
    (
    SELECT 1 as ID
    UNION
    SELECT 2 as ID
    UNION
    SELECT 3 as ID
    UNION
    SELECT 4 as ID
    ) a LEFT JOIN table1 b
        ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.ID IN (1,2,3,4)
```

**UPDATE 1**

You could simply generate a table that have 1 column preferably with name (*ID*) that has records maybe up 10,000 or more. Then you could simply join it with your table that has the original record. For Example, **assuming that you have a table named `DummyRecord` with 1 column and has 10,000 rows on it**

```
SELECT a.id, b.name, coalesce(b.`count`) as `count`
FROM   DummyRecord a LEFT JOIN table1 b
        ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.ID >= 1 AND 
      a.ID <= 4
```

that's it. Or if you want to have from 10 to 100, then you could use this condition

```
...
WHERE a.ID >= 10 AND 
      a.ID <= 100
```

Comment: The table have lot of rows not only one to 4.we need to take it dynamically

Answer (score 3):

To clarify this is how one can append an extra row to the result set

```
select * from table union select 123 as id,'abc' as name
```

results

```
 id  | name
------------
***  |  ***
***  |  ***
123  |  abc
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use mysql [ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
      GROUP BY Name WITH ROLLUP;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  x.id,
  t.name,
  ifnull(t.count, 0) as count
from
  (SELECT 1 AS id
    -- Part of the query below, you will need to generate dynamically,
    -- just as you would otherwise need to generate 'in (1,2,3,4)'
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
    UNION ALL SELECT 3
    UNION ALL SELECT 4
    UNION ALL SELECT 5
  ) x
  LEFT JOIN YourTable t 
    ON t.id = x.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` does not exist in the table you're selecting from, you'll need to `LEFT JOIN` against a list of every `id` you want returned - this way, it will return the `null` values for ones that don't exist and the true values for those that do.

I would suggest creating a `numbers` table that is a single-columned table filled with numbers:

```
CREATE TABLE `numbers` (
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
);
```

And then inserting a large amount of numbers, starting at `1` and going up to what you think the highest `id` you'll ever see plus a thousand or so. Maybe go from `1` to `1000000` to be on the safe side. Regardless, you just need to make sure it's more-than-high enough to cover any possible `id` you'll run into.

After that, your query can look like:

```
SELECT n.id, a.*
FROM
    `numbers` n
    LEFT JOIN table t
        ON t.id = n.id
WHERE n.id IN (1,2,3,4);
```

This solution will allow for a dynamically growing list of `ids` without the need for a sub-query with a list of unions; though, the other solutions provided will equally work for a small known list too (and could also be dynamically generated).

Comment: You must not forget to make sure the numbers table is large enough. This is something that can be easily forgotten, if someone decides to put 'about a million' records in it, and after a few years the other table grows to over a million. (Yes, that happens!) But otherwise it is a nice alternative to my answer. You still need to 'generate' a part of the query, though (the list of numbers), so it's not much easier.